# jquery nextUntil match nested elements

Tags: jquery, html

How do you use `nextUntil()` (https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) in jquery 3.2.1 to add a class to elements matched between a group of headings?

Say I have this markup:

```
<h5>Foo</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>

<h5>Bar</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 4</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 5</a></p>

<h5>Baz</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 6</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 7</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 8</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 9</a></p>
```

My intention is to add a `.active` class to all `<a>` elements beneath a given `<h5>`.

I understand I can target the click on the `<h5>` like this:

```
$('h5').click(function(e) {

});
```

But if I try and use this:

```
$('h5').click(function(e) {
    $(this).nextUntil('h5').addClass('active');
});
```

It won't work because it's adding the `.active` to the `<p>` instead of the `<a>`, e.g. clicking "Bar":

```
<h5>Bar</h5>
<p class="active"><a href="#">Item 4</a></p>
<p class="active"><a href="#">Item 5</a></p>
```

Whereas I want:

```
<h5>Bar</h5>
<p><a class="active" href="#">Item 4</a></p>
<p><a class="active" href="#">Item 5</a></p>
```

How can I target the `<a>` inside this? From the documentation on `nextUntil()` I can't see how this would work because the selector passed, `h5`, relates to

> A string containing a selector expression to indicate where to **stop** matching following sibling elements.

So this is correct because I want to stop at the next `<h5>`.

The only other things targetted are the `<h5>` I have clicked on - which must remain because that tells it which elements to apply the `nextUntil()` condition on.

So how can you target the inner selector, e.g. `p > a`, below each heading?

Comment: What happens if you try `$(this).nextUntil('h5').children().addClass('active')`?

Comment: It ends up with `.active` on both the `<p>` and `<a>`. I only want it on the `<a>`

Comment: See my answer (or Cuong's) for a working example.

Comment: @Andy Pretty sure you're making a mistake somewhere. `.children()` would select only the `a` tags.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes my mistake. I think there was some old js in the console from testing that was making this happen. `.children()` works as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to combine `.nextUntil()` with [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to do this.

Demo:

```js
$('h5').click(function(e) {
    $(this).nextUntil('h5').find("a").addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>Foo</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>

<h5>Bar</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 4</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 5</a></p>

<h5>Baz</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 6</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 7</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 8</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 9</a></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('h5').click(function(e) {
    $(this).nextUntil('h5').children().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h5>Foo</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 2</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 3</a></p>

<h5>Bar</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 4</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 5</a></p>

<h5>Baz</h5>
<p><a href="#">Item 6</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 7</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 8</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Item 9</a></p>
```

Is this what you are looking for? I simply changed the function to target [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/).